# postgreSQL - Countings "islands" that meet conditions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'm working in PostgreSQL 9.5. I am working with accelerometer data in a table from which I would like to focus on "islands" of inactivity where x OR y < 15 for at least 10 minutes (or 2 consecutive data points)). More specifically, I need to count the number of "islands" that occur per activity_sensors_code each day, and am also interested in the start/stop time of these periods of time.

```
  data_id    activity_sensors_code   band_id   acquisition_time   activity_x   activity_y   temp   insert_timestamp   loaf_count  
  33607382   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:00   11           45           30     10:27.4                        
  33607383   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:05   15           44           30     10:27.4                        
  33607384   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:10   9            42           31     10:27.4                        
  33607385   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:15   23           93           32     10:27.4                        
  33607386   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:20   16           74           32     10:27.4                        
  33607387   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:25   8            0            30     10:27.4            1           
  33607388   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:30   1            0            29     10:27.4            1           
  33607389   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:35   0            0            30     10:27.4            1           
  33607390   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:40   0            0            30     10:27.4            1           
  33607391   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:45   2            9            30     10:27.4            1           
  33607392   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:50   4            10           30     10:27.4            1           
  33607393   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 18:55   0            1            30     10:27.4            1           
  33607394   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 19:00   27           132          30     10:27.4                        
  33607395   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 19:05   7            44           30     10:27.4                        
  33607396   60437                   B024      10/17/2015 19:10   18           63           30     10:27.4
```

Desired result:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| collar_id | count  | timestamp_start | timestamp_end  |
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 60437     | 1      |10/17/2015 18:25 |10/17/2015 18:55|
+-----------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Where there are additional "islands" , they should be counted sequentially until the end of that day, and then counting should restart.To start I'm trying to use dense_rank to number each of the "islands" except I'm only getting back ones.
The code below is my attempt to do the counting part, I haven't gotten past this step yet because I'm getting only 1's.

```
UPDATE analysis.nb_60437
SET
loaf_count = i.lfct
FROM (
SELECT 
DENSE_RANK () 
OVER (PARTITION BY     DATE_PART('month',acquisition_time),DATE_PART('day',acquisition_time)
ORDER BY nonbreeding_data_animals_id,activity_sensors_code ASC
) AS lfct
FROM 
analysis.nb_60437
)i
WHERE 
DATE_PART('hour',nb_60437.acquisition_time) BETWEEN 11 AND 23 AND 
nb_60437.activity_x < 15 OR nb_60437.activity_y < 15;
```